# Subtracting Binary Files

Tags: files

I have 2 Binary Files `FileA` and `FileC`

Its is such that `FileC = FileA + FileB` using the `cat` utility

How do I subtract  `FileA`  from  `FileC`  to get  `FileB` ?

Comment: You use cat for binary files?

Comment: I use `cat` instead of using HJsplit or software like that .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Possible using the `dd` utility:

```
dd if=FileC of=FileB bs=1 skip=$(stat -c %s FileA)
```

See [`man dd`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/man1/dd.1.html) for details.